# Jquery Label selector with variable appended not working

Tags: jquery

label selector with variable appended

```
 var altRoute= getAlternateRoute(route);
  $("label[for='b-'+altRoute+'-0-option']").addClass("muted");
```

This code snippet is not working? what am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misplaced quotes. Use like this,

```
var altRoute = getAlternateRoute(route);
$("label[for='b-" + altRoute + "-0-option']").addClass("muted");
```

Answer (score 3):

It should look like this if you want to use the `altRoute` inside

```
$("label[for='b-"+altRoute+"-0-option']")
```

Answer (score 2):

You're embedding altRoute in the string, rather than concatenating it's value in. Try this:

```
var altRoute= getAlternateRoute(route);
$("label[for='b-" + altRoute + "-0-option']").addClass("muted");
```

Answer (score 1):

you pass the variable in the string so put double quotes and concatnate

```
$("label[for='b-"+altRoute+"-0-option']").addClass("muted");
```

Comment: You need to remove the single quote after `b-` and before `-0`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in quotes. Following will work fine

```
$("label[for='b-"+ altRoute + "-0-option']").addClass("muted");
```