# Concatenation of selector with dynamic value not working - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to remove the style of my **a href** background. The issue is when I concatenate dynamic id with selector then it don't work. But when I use complete name of selector, then it works.
I know you can mark my question as duplicate like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547595/jquery-label-selector-with-variable-appended-not-working) but they are not working for me. Please correct me.

**What Works:**

```
$("a").click(function(event) 
{
     var id = event.target.id;
     $('#chatIdStyle4').removeAttr("style");
});
```

**What Didn't:**

```
$("a").click(function(event) 
{
     var id = event.target.id;
     $('#chatIdStyle'+id).removeAttr("style");
});
```

OR

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
      //alert(event.target.id);
      var iddds = event.target.id;
      $('#chatIdStyle["'+ iddds + '"]').removeAttr("style");
});
```

NOTE: var id contains the dynamic id of event fired.

**EDIT as asked:**

Below is my HTML+PHP code. So, what it does is actually creates 4 dynamic **a href** with dynamic id. What I
want is when a specific **a href** gets clicked then it should remove previous **a href** background and
add background to the clicked **a href**.

```
<?php
    $color = false;
    $PID = 4;
    for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
    {
?>
    <a <?php if($color==true)
            {
                ?> style="background-color: #E6E6E6;" <?php
            }
            $color=false;
        ?>
        id="chatIdStyle<?php echo $PID; ?>"
        href="#">
    </a>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: is it an ID as in `id=""` ?

Comment: Maybe try to debug your code?

Comment: What is the output you are getting for `console.log( event.target.id )`? `4` or `chatIdStyle4`?

Comment: if `id` already contains dynamic `id` then why concat `chatIdStyle`? why not use directly `$('#' + event.target.id)`

Comment: @palaѕн yes it gave me 4

Comment: Also there should never be a situation where you need to concatenate IDs, as an element can only have 1 anyway.

Comment: Can you give us an example ID of a `chatIdStyleXXX` element?

Comment: Can you please post a functional example that illustrates your problem. You can also click `<>` icon in the header in edit mode to add a demo.

Comment: @VipinKumar But what if I want to change background of some other id?

Comment: I would go with @palaѕн to add a function example as a fiddle or snippet

Comment: Please read [mcve]. Your problem depends a DOM elements that we don't have any information about.

Comment: your codes are not wrong, but it depends on the context... can you provide an html example?

Comment: Added more info to the question. Please review. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using CSS solution instead of jQuery:

```
a { background: none; }
a:active { background: #E6E6E6; }
```

The second line will set the background for the last clicked `a` element.

About the `:active` pseudo class: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp